# How do you get code used on both the client and the server to load before all code in server/ and client/ folders?

Tags: meteor

I have some code that is used on both the client and the server, that I need to be loaded before all code in `server/` and `client/`

I tried to put the common code in `lib/`, but then I run into issues when I have code in `client/lib` and `server/lib` that depends on the code in `lib/` to be defined when they load.

Here's an example of file load order from [the Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) under the section File Load Order:

```
nav.html
main.html
client/lib/methods.js
client/lib/styles.js
lib/feature/styles.js
lib/collections.js
client/feature-y.js
feature-x.js
client/main.js
```

According to this example, files in `client/lib/` get loaded before files in `lib/`.

I need the files in `lib/` to load before the files in `client/lib/`. Is there any way to change this?

I'm putting my collection definitions in `lib/`, and my client subscriptions in `client/lib`. Organizing it like this makes sense to me because, my helpers in `client/helpers.js` depend on `client/lib/subscriptions.js`, and my subscriptions depend on the collections defined in `lib/collections.js`, and both the client and the server need the collection definitions, so I put them in `lib/`.

Comment: From what you've described, everything should work fine. Since everything is reactive, most of the time it doesn't matter the order the files are loaded. especially in regards to subscriptions and client side helpers. Do you have any particular things that aren't working that would help to clarify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found a clever solution.

I essentially renamed `./client/lib/` to `./client/deps/`, which changed the load order to the following.

```
./lib/collections.js
./client/deps/subscriptions.js
./client/helpers.js
```

I need this order because my subscriptions depend on a collection being defined, and my helpers depend on subscriptions being defined.

The folder `./client/lib/` will always be loaded before `./lib/`, but `./client/deps/` will be loaded after `./lib/` and before `./client/helpers.js`, because `./client/deps/` is a deeper folder than `./client/`, as per the Meteor documentation on File Load Order.

Comment: There are 3 ways to avoid doing it this way. that would most likely be better. First, you can put subscriptions in iron:router. Second, you can put all of your subscriptions in `client/main.js` which is loaded last. Finally,  you could do template level subscriptions. I think you are misunderstanding Meteor. your helpers are reactive, so whenever your subscriptions are ready, they will work. it doesnt matter which file is loaded first